# Проблема с импортом из .pyd при запуске программы из .exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller, auto-py-to-exe, psutil

Скомпилировал .py в .exe, но при запуске программы выходит ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "check_processes.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Sergey\PycharmProjects\EXE Timer\output\check_processes\psutil\__init__.py", line 109, in <module>
    from . import _pswindows as _psplatform
  File "C:\Users\Sergey\PycharmProjects\EXE Timer\output\check_processes\psutil\_pswindows.py", line 35, in <module>
    from ._psutil_windows import ABOVE_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _psutil_windows: Не найден указанный модуль.
```

Файл _psutil_windows - это файл .pyd. Я так понимаю, проблема именно в этом. Через PyCharm всё работает, всё в порядке. А при запуске из .exe - нет.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: файл не запаковался в архив экзешника. настроить модуль на полную упаковку надо

Comment: Могли бы вы конкретнее сказать, какие файлы и т.д.? Модуль psutil в папке есть, и программа, я так понимаю, видит его.

Comment: В какой папке он есть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал компиляцию без каких-либо проблем с помощью модуля cx_Freeze. Если что, хороший урок от Яндекса: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FsBx87uRT_I&t=1598s&ab_channel=MoscowPython